# How to format linux mpstat output in multiple lines

Tags: linux, bash, shell, quote

I have a small script where I appended the output of linux mpstat to a log file.

```
#/bin/bash
CPU_USAGE=$(mpstat)
echo $CPU_USAGE >> temp.log
```

The problem is that the output of mpstat on the terminal is formatted properly in 3 lines like so

[image]

However, the output to the file is all in one line.

[image]

How do I format the output like the one on the terminal?

Comment: On SO we don't encourage samples to be presented in form of images, please post them in text form and let us know then.

Comment: how about mpstat >> temp.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just quote the variable so it is not seen as several different parameters to be printed one after the other:

```
echo "$CPU_USAGE" >> temp.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just directly pipe the output to the file:

```
#!/bin/bash
mpstat >> temp.log
```

If you must store it in a variable, then quote it like:

```
#!/bin/bash
CPU_USAGE=$(mpstat)
echo "$CPU_USAGE" >> temp.log
```

Otherwise, bash will not interpret the newlines as part of the message to echo, but the whole output as a list of short strings to output.